# Taking the difference of 2 nodes in a decision problem while keeping the model as an MILP

Tags: optimization, pyomo, mixed-integer-programming

To explain the question it's best to start with this
[picture](https://ibb.co/WPNxwWV)

I am modeling an optimization decision problem and a feature that I'm trying to implement is heat transfer between the process stages (a = 1, 2) taking into account which equipment type is chosen (j = 1, 2, 3) by the binary decision variable y.

The temperatures for the equipment are fixed values and my goal is to find (in the case of the picture) dT = 120 - 70 = 50 while keeping the temperature difference as a parameter (I want to keep the problem linear and need to multiply the temperature difference with a variable later on).

Things I have tried:

```
dT = T[a,j] - T[a-1,j]
```

(this obviously gives T = 80 for T[a-1,j] which is incorrect)

```
T[a-1] = sum(T[a-1,j] * y[a-1,j] for j in (1,2,3)
```

This will make the problem non-linear when I multiply with another variable.

I am using pyomo and the linear "glpk" solver. Thank you for reading my post and if someone could help me with this it is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 2 stages and 3 pieces of equipment at each stage, you could reformulate and let a binary decision variable `Y[i]` represent each of the 9 possible connections and `delta_T[i]` be a parameter that represents the temp difference associated with the same 9 connections which could easily be calculated and put into a model parameter.

If you want to keep in double-indexed, and assuming that there will only be 1 piece of equipment selected at each stage, you could take the sum-product of the selection variable and temps at each stage and subtract them.

```
dT[a] = sum(T[a, j]*y[a, j] for j in J) - sum(T[a-1, j]*y[a-1, j] for j in J)
```

for a ∈ {2, 3, ..., N}

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This does unfortunately not solve the problem. The first suggestion would indeed work for the small example I provided but not for the actual problem I am trying to solve. The second suggestion is in a sense the same approach as I described in my original post (the second attempt). This is not an ideal solution since later on I need to multiply dT with variable F[a,j] making the model non-linear. I want to avoid formulating a MINLP problem.

Comment: There is probably a way to reformulate...  can you edit your post and put in a bit more info about the constraint you need with `F[a,j]`?